# How to delete specific data from $_SESSION on click

Tags: php, session

I am building a super simple program with CRUD type capabilities. Instead of data being stored in a database, it is stored in the $_SESSION. Users enter a number and it is stored in the $_SESSION. Each number currently stored in the $_SESSION is displayed on the screen. Next to each number displayed, I want there to be a link or button of some sorts that will delete that specific number from $_SESSION when clicked.

Right now, I have a delete function that allows a user to enter a number and it will delete it from $_SESSION. However, I am having trouble converting this functionality to a link / button functionalitz of some sorts that appears next to every stored number and that will delete that specific number from $_SESSION when clicked.

```
// this is my current delete function described above
 function delete_article () {

  if (isset($_POST['delete']) && is_numeric($_POST['delete'])) {

   foreach($_SESSION['articles'] as $k => $v) {
        if($v == $_POST['delete'])
            //var_dump($_SESSION['articles']);
            unset($_SESSION['articles'][$k]);
    }

    } 
  }
  //to display the results on the screen, I use a function that
  //includes the following

  foreach($_SESSION['articles'] as $item){
    echo $item . '<br>';
   }
```

There are no error messages, just I can't get the functionality to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this code in a file say sess_del.php.

After this in HTML provide a link on button like this:

Please Note : You will have to change the REQUEST method from POST to GET.

if (isset($_GET['delete']) && is_numeric($_GET['delete'])) {

Comment: <a href="sess_del.php?sess_id=<?php echo $sess_id;?>"><button>Delete</button></a> // code for button link